# How to reset a css animation class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, addclass, animate.css

```
    $('#btn_color').on('click', function(){
    if($('h1').hasClass('bounceInUp')){

        $('h1').removeClass('bounceInUp');
        $('h1').addClass('tada');

    }else if($('h1').hasClass('tada')){

        $('h1').removeClass('tada');
        $('h1').addClass('tada');

    }
});
```

When I load my page, the 'bounceInUp' class is added to my `h1`.
But I want to play a second animation on click by adding the 'tada' class.

The problem is the animation plays only for the first click.
Is there a way to "reload" the animation when the 'tada' class is added again and again and again?

I'm using this to animate my text using this:
http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edited

You can attach single listener of `animationend` event to remove animation classes when animation ends

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn_color', function (e) {
    $('h1').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function (e) {
        $('h1').removeClass('animated bounceInUp');
    });

    $('h1').removeClass('animated bounceInUp').addClass('animated bounceInUp');
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/nb57ke5o/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You could jquery's `setTimeout` to remove the class once the animation finishes:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('h1').removeClass('tada');
}, 3000); // The length of your animation
```

Comment: Nice, I like the solution

Answer (score 1):

with this simple code you do it ( you must use **.width()** ):

```
$('h1').removeClass('tada');
$('h1').width();
$('h1').addClass('tada');
```